# Can i use com.android.internal.Itelephony?

Tags: java, android

I ask if i can use the com.android.internal.Itelephony and use the methode of this package.
i can implemet this interface a exoloit the methods includ in this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so. The `ITelephony` package is internal so you cannot get reference it in the standard format else you use reflection to access the methods. e.g

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Method m1 = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m1.setAccessible(true);
Object iTelephony = m1.invoke(tm);

Method m3 = iTelephony.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("endCall"); 

m2.invoke(iTelephony);
```

You will need the following permissions to make it work

> `READ_PHONE_STATE`
>
> `CALL_PHONE`

Note in some cases it might not work until you add the permission `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` which is granted to system apps only

Comment: Also note that reflection of this form is being banned, at least in part, with Android P.